# USRP to generate a beacon

Tags: gnuradio, usrp

I would like to use my USRP E110 to generate a wave signal at aspecific frequency . I want to use the USRP as a beacon to generate this signal . I think there is a way I can do it directly on the hard drive rather than GNU radio. Could any one help in this regard please.
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

This question is very broad, and unclear. You say you want to use an USRP, but not GNU Radio. Also, what is the 'wave signal' you want to generate?

I suggest taking this to the usrp-users mailing list.